# iOS 6 orientation changes have me totally confused

Tags: iphone, ios6, orientation

This is a universal app and I have the supported interface orientations for both iPhone and iPad targets set only to Landscape Left and Right. My root view controllers do not use a NavigationController and the xibs are landscape oriented views. The app is designed to only use the landscape orientations.

In application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions I have...

```
if (([JLHelper isIPhone]) | ([JLHelper iPadPortraitRestricted])) {
         application.statusBarOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
```

In iOS 5 everything worked fine but In iOS 6 the view does not display in a landscape orientation on startup.

I understand that shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation has been deprecated in iOS 6, but I do not understand why this affects the initial presentation. It appears to me that the root view is being rotated.

I have read many discussions on how to force landscape orientation in iOS 6 and am now totally confused. There must be a simple way to implement an app that only uses landscape orientation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the supported orientations in the info.plist for iOS 6. Additionally you can implement the shouldAutorotate method and the supportedInterfaceOrientations methods (new as of iOS 6) to conditionally restrict orientations for iOS 6.

Note that if you want to continue to support iOS 5 you also have to have the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation... method in place. iOS 5 uses the old method, iOS 6 the new one, they can coexist.

Comment: Thanks for replying. The landscape orientations are implemented in the info.plist, in my case jetLogger-info.plist. I have also included in my root viewController the methods shouldAutorotate, returning NO, and supportedInteraceOrientations, returning UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape. The view still does not display in landscape.

Comment: Ok I got it working. shouldAutorotaate has to return YES. The new changes make sense to me now. shouldAutorotate simply declares whether the app should allow autorotation regardless of orientation. supportedInterfaceOrientations controls which orientations will autorotate. I found that you do not need to call supportedInterfaceOrientations if you have the orientations implemented in you info.plist

Comment: One important note. In order for the whole thing to work you must use  window.rootViewController = viewController; instead of [window addSubview:viewController.view]; in your application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions method.

Comment: yep, the rootViewController on window has been there since iOS 3, but like many developers we had just left the old code we had from the Xcode template which continued to work all the way up to iOS 5.1. iOS 6 is the first that NEEDS the rootViewController set.